# Read CSV file with specific columns as String in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large file which is dynamically generated, a small sample of which is given below:

```
ID,FEES,I_CLSS
11,5555,00000110
12,5555,654321
13,5555,000030
14,5555,07640
15,5555,14550
17,5555,99070
19,5555,090090
```

My issue is that I will always have a column like `I_CLSS` that is starting with `0`s in this file. I'd like to read the file to a spark dataframe with `I_CLSS` column as StringType.

For this, in python I can do something like,

`df = pandas.read_csv('INPUT2.csv',dtype={'I_CLSS': str})`

But is there an alternative to this command in pyspark?

I understand that I can manually specify the schema of a file in Pyspark. But it would be extremely diffficult to do for a file whose columns are dynamically generated.

So I'd appreciate it if somebody could help me with this.

Comment: Do the column names correspond to the type in any way? Can you dynamically build the schema as well?

Comment: @cricket_007:Building schema dynamically would be quite difficult. Is there any way to read only a specific column as StringType. Some workaround with `inferSchema="true"`?

Comment: I believe by default, everything is a string type. You can cast specific columns to other types later. But if you had a prefix of i for int, then s for string in the columns and preserved ordering, then generating a schema wouldn't be that hard

Comment: Can you show me how to cast specific columns to other types in a dataframe?

Comment: There's a cast function in SparkSQL